# Cloning a fortrabbit app to another fortrabbit account without its dashboard/git credentials

Tags: fortrabbit

A developer was paid to develop an app.  He used fortrabbit.  He is abandoning his role as developer and has provided credentials only for sftp, mysql and rsynch to the client that paid for this app to be developed.

Obviously, the client would prefer to make a copy of the fortrabbit app in an account that he controls (ie: to which he has the dashboard credentials).

Is there a tool or cookbook about how to do this?  If not how would one go about taking an sftp get -rP * copy of the app (with mysql database backup) and recreate the development, deployment and hosting environment of fortrabbit for the app in the fortrabbit account controlled by the client that paid for this development?

Comment: Did you found a solution to your problem ? If you have ssh access, you can have the code, view the environment variables, and you probably know what was the price of the app, so you should be able to create a similar environment.

Answer (score 1):

in the current dashboard, the developer can start an [owner-change](http://fortrabbit.com/docs/in-depth/permission-management) > invite the new owner by mail to take over the App.

the new dashboard will feature a more sophisticated model to map such business relationships.

i am not quite sure if this question should be posted here on SO. fortrabbit questions here should always be related to coding and of special interested.